# (.net) What is the best way to make a locally running web application that can ported to IIS later?

Tags: c#, html, http, thick-client

I would like to make a command line exe application that serves dynamic content via http. However, at least for now, I don't want it to undergo any setup that requires the user to have IIS.

It will not have to serve any heavy loads, just take one request at a time from the local user.

Reasons for wanting this:

1. I want it to look nice, and I have more experience in html/css than in thick client display frameworks, and I don't have a lot of time to devote to this project
2. I want people to be able to run it without knowing how to configure IIS
3. If enough people find it useful, I want to be able to easily convert it to a full-fledged web application later

Are there established methods for making this happen aside from setting up a System.Net.WebRequest listenier and writing parsing code?

Comment: There are libraries out there which make it extremely simple to implement basic HTTP servers.  One example is this one: https://github.com/qoollo/SharpHttpServer

Available as a nuget package.  Search for "Quollo.SharpHTTPServer".

Comment: @HaukurHaf this seems to be exactly what I was looking for, googled for a while and did not find this.

Comment: @HaukurHaf although, there does not seem to be good documentation on how to consume it

Comment: @TheCatWhisperer I'm sorry but this is not the place for asking that kind of questions. Please read [ask]

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I understand... any appropriate SE for asking for framework/code recommendations?

Comment: Unfortunately, not really, as they tend to be opinionated/spam which is what this site strives to avoid.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I see; guess I'll have to role my own :( 

Will take as much time as I planned to devote to the other parts of this project

Comment: Do notice, though, that ASP.NET Core provides the ability to host an application without requiring IIS, as an .exe/dll  application, both for .NET and .NET Core. "Kestrel is a cross-platform HTTP server based on libuv, a cross-platform asynchronous I/O library.
HTTP.sys is a Windows-only HTTP server based on the Http.Sys kernel driver."